# Array not working with will_paginate, despite requiring 'will_paginate/array'?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, will-paginate

I have a Search model that constructs a string that is basically raw SQL. This string runs through a find_by_sql call, and is returned to the controller on line 5 below (@search.query <--query is the method that returns the result of find_by_sql):

```
1  def roster_builder
2    authorize! :access_roster_builder, current_coach
3    @search = Search.new(sport: current_coach.primary_sport, conditions: params[:search])
4
5    @athletes = @search.query.page(params[:page]).per_page(8)
6
7    if params[:refresh]
8      render "athletes_refresh" 
9    else
10     render "athletes" if request.format.js?
11   end
12 end
```

This returns an array, but I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `page' for #<Array:0x00000105b7add0>)
```

So I found where inserting the following should remedy this:

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

I've tried putting that in my controller, and the will_paginate.rb initializer file to no avail. I've even done .to_a on the find_by_sql result--same error. What exactly is the problem here?? I'm using will_paginate version 3.0.4, so it's completely up-to-date. On github, it even says the require should make this work fine: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Backwards-incompatibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this post: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/263

So for your controller it would look like this

```
def roster_builder
    require 'will_paginate/array'
  authorize! :access_roster_builder, current_coach
  @search = Search.new(sport: current_coach.primary_sport, conditions: params[:search])

  # @athletes = @search.query.page(params[:page]).per_page(8)
    @athletes = @search.query.paginate page: params[:page], per_page: 8

  if params[:refresh]
    render "athletes_refresh" 
  else
    render "athletes" if request.format.js?
  end
end
```